# Get selected radio

Tags: python, django

I want to know what radio is selected after clicking a submit button.

My forms.py:

```
class forum(forms.Form):
CHOICES = (('select1', 'select 1'), ('select2', 'select 2'))
choix = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
query = forms.CharField(label='Product name',max_length=100,required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `choice = form.cleaned_data['choix']` in the POST handler of the view. As Django is an MVC framework not an SPA framework you do not have the knowledge of what is going on in the browsers session in any way (unless you write your own JS to hit a custom endpoint) as it is plain HTML (as far as Django knows) not anything more.

--*MORE INFO*--

Form data access: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#field-data

Form fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/